# Ruby on Rails: Getting an extra record that is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database

I noticed that when I create a record in one of my tables, and I have some kind of data that is associated with that table, it adds 1 record already, but it is nil?

For instance:

**lists controller**

```
  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @idea = @list.ideas.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @list }
    end
  end
```

**list model**

```
has_many :ideas
```

**idea model**

```
belongs_to :list
```

**list > show.html.erb**

```
<%= @list.ideas.each do |idea| %>
  <div>
    <div class="list_idea_desc"><%= idea.description %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Show', idea %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Destroy', idea, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>   </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get this record:

```
[#<Idea id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, 
picture: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, list_id: 1>]
```

This `idea` record automatically gets inserted into my database when I create a new list. Why does this happen?

Comment: It was not inserted in your database, it is just being displayed because you build it in the controller. I'm deducting that because Idea have id: nil

Comment: @user1438190 I'm new to rails, can you give me a little more detail as to what my alternative is? I really appreciate it.

Comment: What is your objective? Why you added `@idea = @list.ideas.build` ?

Comment: you can call `persisted?` method to verify that this idea was not saved

Comment: flagged as not a real question

Comment: On terminal run `rails console` and there you can run `Idea.all` or `List.last.ideas` and check if the Idea was created

Comment: @user1438190 you're right, it doesn't get saved. I'm not sure why I added it. I was following a tutorial that they added after having a relationship between two tables. So I figured I needed this if I have the two ideas and lists relationship? I also have added `add_foreign_key :ideas, :lists` in my `create_ideas` migration file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difference between `new` and `build` is that `build` adds the newly created object to the collection:

**Replace:**

```
@idea = @list.ideas.build
```

**With:**

```
@idea = @list.ideas.new
```

---

Or if you want to use `build` only, you should

**Replace:**

```
<%= @list.ideas.each do |idea| %>
```

**With:**

```
<%= @list.ideas(true).each do |idea| %>
```

[`true` discards the cached copy of ideas and goes back to the database.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching)

Comment: I changed it per your code, now I'm getting a no route matches, which isn't true because I do have the correct routing?

Comment: OH genius!!! Thank you very much! you solved so many problems i have! Is `true` normally used a lot? Or is this just a "hack" to get rid of my problems?

Comment: @shweta as per rails 3.2+ `build` is an alias for `new` now

Answer (score 1):

This is due to `@idea = @list.ideas.build` code line, remove it and check it.
It may works for your view.

```
<% @idea = @list.ideas.build %>
<%= form_for [@list,@idea] do |f| %>
```

Comment: If I remove that then I get a `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class` with my form, which I have `<%= form_for [@list,@idea] do |f| %>`.

Comment: You can include this code in your view above the form, but it is not good idea

Comment: Thanks for the update, but if you say its not a good idea, is there another suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<%= @list.ideas.each do |idea| %>
  <% if idea.present? %>
  <div>
    <div class="list_idea_desc"><%= idea.description %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Show', idea %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Destroy', idea, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>                   </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Use **present?** condition in record saving time also.